# Nginx change request_uri in order to proxy redirect to the right url

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

I want to be able to redirect several requests to different containers running in the same machine.
To do this I am trying to use nginx.

Conf file I am using at the moment:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  location /foo{
    proxy_pass "http://1.1.0.2:10";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /bar{
    proxy_pass "http://1.1.0.3:10";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

My problem is that the `/foo` and `/bar` are just like tags in order to know to which container to redirect. By doing this way the `/foo` and `/bar` are being sent as a `$request_uri` that will result in an error. I want to filter them or change them to `/` alone.

As an example when doing `http.myip.com/`foo
i want to redirect to `http://1.1.0.2:10/` only.

I tried some rewrites but it seems I am not getting lucky.

Comment: If you use a trailing `/` on both the `location` value and `proxy_pass` value, then Nginx will perform the initial translation for you. For example: `location /foo/ { proxy_pass http://1.1.0.2:10/; ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith My problem is by doing that it will redirect to http://1.1.0.2:10/foo/...  and i want by specifying the location of /foo to redirect only to http://1.1.0.2:10/

Comment: nvm that fixed half the problems, the other half is the images not loading

Comment: In general, your apps behind `/foo` and `/bar` locations need to be aware that they are in such locations, and generate URLs in their HTML output respectively.